# "Comfortable" horizontal acceleration/deceleration

Tags: forces, acceleration, biophysics, perception

### Overall

> What is a comfortable horizontal acceleration/deceleration?

---

### Details

I speak of average civilians, not fighters pilots pulling off $9$ $G$s.

Let's say that people on the vehicle are either sitting or standing while grabbing on to a bar.

For example, bus acceleration and decelerations are quite comfortable. However, could they be higher without disturbing the riders?

I apologize for the ambiguity of "comfortable", because I can't quantitate it.

---

### Disclaimer

This question might deserve to be in some engineering SE site; in case some of you believe it shouldn't be here, please recommend a better SE site to post this on.

Comment: Do you have a smartphone?  Download the [Graphical Analysis app](http://www.vernier.com/products/software/ga-app) or something like it and measure accelerations on a bus etc. to get an idea of what is comfortable.

Comment: @M.Enns: I haven't been on a bus recently, nor do I have plans to in the near future. `:)` But, yes, I do have a smartphone. Thanks for the suggestion, though! _(Note: In case anyone's going on a bus as they answer this question, please send me the results of M.Enn's suggested app `:)`)_

Comment: Probably better on engineering, all things considered. VTC. If you look up bus manufactures website,  or government road safety standards for example, they may have data.

Comment: @count_to_10: Pardon me, but what's VTC?

Comment: Oh dear, I'm sorry to say have to say this,  it's vote to close. But check about migration to engineering before its closed, I am not sure of the protocol if you decide to migrate it to engineering. Best of luck with it.

Comment: @count_to_10: No problem. I just didn't know the abbreviation. Thanks, and I'll go ahead and migrate the question elsewhere.

Comment: Actually biologySE makes more sense to me or something related to medicine

Comment: If this is about perception then you can ask this question in [biology.se]. However, you must add more relevant details such as clarification of what "disturbance" or "comfort" might be. Moreover, different people may have different sensitivities to acceleration. So you may consider asking first if there is a level of acceleration that may feel nauseating/uncomfortable and then you can ask what the general range of that might be (for untrained). Additionally, you can ask how the body actually responds in these situations. Therefore, it is best to ask a new improvised question in [biology.se].

Comment: @WYSIWYG: I reported my question to move it to Biology but no one did it. Should I delete this here and rewrite it there?

Comment: @SirJony since this post is already closed, you can ask a new question in Biology. Deleting is not necessary but you can, if you wish.

Comment: I asked the biology modes if they wanted this and the reply was *"That could be rephrased properly to be suitable for Biology. However, since the question is already closed on Physics, you can rather suggest the OP to ask a new question in biology, with some additional details."*.

Comment: @dmckee & WYSIWYG: OK, thanks. I'm busy ATM but I'll do as suggested either today or tomorrow. _(This message will self-destruct once I complete the task.)_